# How to fix 'ImportError: No module named pox.core' in pox controller code

Tags: python, pox

this is my code :

```
from pox.core import core
import pox.openflow.libopenflow_01 as of
from pox.lib.util import dpid_to_str
from pox.lib.util import str_to_bool

from pox.lib.addresses import EthAddr
from pox.lib.packet.ethernet import ethernet
import pox.lib.packet as pkt
```

and i have an error with:

```
File "d:/SDN/pox-master/pox/sw1.py", line 7, in <module>
from pox.core import core
ImportError: No module named pox.core
```

is there any solutions to fix

Comment: are you sure, you installed pox, if not check: https://noxrepo.github.io/pox-doc/html/#installing-pox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't have pox installed.
Now POX is available on the PyPy Python runtime.

Install pox with this command :

```
pip install pox
```

You can install it from source as well, for more information : https://pypi.org/project/pox/

Comment: This is no longer the pox package the author asked. He/she asked for the pip package of this repo (https://github.com/noxrepo/pox) and https://pypi.org/project/pox/ points to https://github.com/uqfoundation/pox which is a totally different thing, not the SDN pox (networking software platform)

Answer (score 1):

As Thien Phan says, the `pox` library for SDN is not installed with `pip` and is only compatible with Python 2. I "installed" `pox` following this link:

https://noxrepo.github.io/pox-doc/html/#installing-pox

That is, I cloned the Github project inside mine and switched to the dart branch:

```
git clone http://github.com/noxrepo/pox
cd pox
git checkout dart
```

and created an empty **init**.py file inside the pox directory (this is **important** for the directory to be recognized as a Python package!!)

Please note that if you do this, you would have to import `pox` modules like:

```
from pox.pox.core import getLogger
```

and **NOT** like:

from pox.core import getLogger

and replace **EVERY** import of "pox." to "pox.pox." in the pox directory. Otherwise, you would have import erros.

*The alternative to this is just copying your project files inside the pox directory and work from there.*